# Is $y$ its own inverse if $y$ is symmetric with $x$?

Tags: functions

I was thinking about equations that are their own inverses and noticed that at least some of them are symmetric. $$f(x)=x\implies y=x\implies x=y\implies x=f^{-1}(x)\implies f^{-1}(x)=x$$ $$y=\frac 1x\implies x=\frac 1y\implies x= \frac{1}{f^{-1}(x)}\implies f^{-1}(x)=\frac 1x$$ Similar results happen for functions like $y = 1-x$ and $x^3+y^3=9$. Is there a way to prove that for any symmetric equation in $y$ and $x$, $y=f(x)$ will be its own inverse?

Comment: It is usually enough to say “by symmetry in the rôles of $x$ and $y$…” or “by exchanging (the labels of) $x$ and $y$…”.

Comment: The circle in your list is not a function. We get from your symmetry requirement $y=f(x)$ and $x=f(y)$ hence $x=f(f(x))=f^2(x).$ These are the functions you consider: $f\circ f=\operatorname{id}.$ But you also have to administrate range and domain.

Comment: @miracle173 thanks, I fixed it